# How to use staticcall with inline assembly that returns bytes data?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, evm

I've been trying to write a function that takes `contractAddress` and `bytes functionSignature` as input parameters and returns `bytes data` from the static call in inline assembly.

For some reason it keeps returning `0x0` instead of the data

---

im clearly doing something wrong

```js
function getUintAnswer(address _contractAddress, bytes memory data) public view returns (bytes memory result) {
    assembly {

        // Call the target contract
        let success := staticcall(64000, _contractAddress, data, 4/*input bytes*/, result, 160/*output bytes*/)

        // failed
        if iszero(success) { 
            revert(0, 0) 
            }
    }
}
```

i expected the result to be:

```js
0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000027fa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001bf2c11b5e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000639ce2e300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000639ce2e300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000027fa
```

and got a revert

im trying to extract the second `int256` and cast it to a `uint256` in the most gas efficient way
and i been stuck trying to figure out how to get the static call to successfully return a value

Comment: you should paste the contract code to be tested

Comment: updated, most apologies